# Using Mozilla firefox parser (Rendering Engine) in an extension

Tags: security, firefox, web, firefox-addon

I want to build a Firefox extension which will use Firefox parser(Rendering Engine). I want to feed some HTML data to parser and in return, it will give me HTML and java-script content separately. Then I will do some processing on it. Is there any API or another way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

you mean something like this...

```
let s = "<i>cool</i><script>alert('cool!')</script>";
var parser = new DOMParser();
let doc = parser.parseFromString(s, "text/html");

//do whatever you want....
doc.body.appendChild(doc.createElement('hr'));
alert(doc.documentElement.outerHTML)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing here?

Comment: I'm doing what I thought you wanted, parse HTML source into a DOM document that you can manipulate using standard DOM Methods.

Comment: Wow this is so cool! I didn't know you could do this! How to use this from XPCOM?